# One variable minimization with messy algebra

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm trying to solve the following minimization problem:
$$
\min_{n\in(0,\infty)}f(n)=\;\left(\frac{a}{a+n}-\frac{b}{b+n}\right)^2\left(1+\frac{b}{n}\right)
+\frac{b}{b+n}+nc
\tag{1}
$$
where $a,b,c>0$ and they are fixed parameters. I derived the FOC (first order condition) with respect to $n$ to be
$$
\begin{multline}
2\left(\frac{a}{a+n}-\frac{b}{b+n}\right)
\left(\frac{b}{(b+n)^2}-\frac{a}{(a+n)^2}\right)
\left(1+\frac{b}{n}\right) \\
-\left(\frac{a}{a+n}-\frac{b}{b+n}\right)^2\frac{b}{n^2}
-\frac{b}{(b+n)^2}+c
=0
\end{multline}
$$
This looks very messy. I tried several ways to simplify it but didn't succeed. However, if I plot $(1)$ against $n$, for a number of parameter values, the curve appears to be U-shaped, with a unique minimum. This following figure is plotted using $a=15,b=1.5,c=0.05$. 
[image]

I've tried plotting with different combinations of parameters, and the pattern is largely the same. This suggests that there should be a way to solve the FOC for an explicit solution of $n$, and that this $n$ should be unique. From the FOC, it's not even obvious that the objective function is convex on $(0,\infty)$

Does anyone have an idea on how to simplify the FOC? Any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is an FOC?

Comment: Are a,b,c free to vary or are they fixed and you want the optimal value given their values?

Comment: Let R  = (a/(a+n) - b/(b+n))^2 (1 + b/n)^2+ b/(b+n) + nc, then the minimum value is either a solution to the system $$ \frac{\partial R }{\partial a} = \frac{\partial R }{\partial  b} = \frac{\partial R }{\partial c} = \frac{\partial R }{\partial n} = 0$$ and/or n = 0, and/or some the variables should be set as big (towards infinity) or small towards negative inifnity as possible. But thats a lot of algebra to do!

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: FOC stands for first order condition, in this case with respect to $n$. $a,b,c$ are fixed, positive parameters, and I want to solve for $n$ as a function of the three parameters. I understand that this is a lot of algebra, but given how the plotted curve looks like, the solution should be relatively simple, I think. Also, note that $n\in(0,\infty)$, so $n=0$ is not an option.

Comment: You could end up with behavior that says let n be as close to 0 without being 0, in which case though you excluded 0, you still "effectively" get it as a solution. Additionally, then you can just solve dR/dn = 0, and call it a day there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can be simplified:

$$f(n)=\left(\frac{a}{a+n}-\frac{b}{b+n}\right)^2\left(1+\frac{b}{n}\right)^2
+\frac{b}{b+n}+nc
\tag{1} = \frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+n)^2} + \frac{b}{b+n}+nc,$$
which is convex.

Taking the derivative:
$$f'(n) = -\frac{2(a-b)^2}{(a+n)^3}-\frac{b}{(b+n)^2}+c.$$
Clearly, $f'(n)$ is increasing on $[0,+\infty)$, thus $f'(n) \ge f'(0)= - \frac{2(a-b)^2}{a^3} - \frac{1}{b}+c$.

Therefore, if $c\ge \frac{2(a-b)^2}{a^3} + \frac{1}{b}$ then $f(n)$ attains its minimum at $n=0$.

If  $c < \frac{2(a-b)^2}{a^3} + \frac{1}{b}$ then $f'(n)$ has at least one positive root. Solving $f'(n)=0$ is equivalent to solving a [quintic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function):
$$c(a+n)^3(b+n)^2-b(a+n)^3-2(a-b)^2(b+n)^2 = 0$$

Of course without a specific relation between $a,b$ and $c$, one cannot solve the equation analytically.

If you want to **numerically** solve the original optimization problem,  you can use gradient descent method for example, since the function is convex.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry I have made a typo in my question: the term $(1+\frac{b}{n})$ is **not** squared. I'm very sorry! Regarding the relation between the three parameters, I can assume $a>b>c$. Would this help in pinning down an analytic solution?

Comment: @HerrK. : You can still simplify the function a bit. The polynomial is now of an even higher degree and I don't think it is possible to derive an analytical solution, given simply $a>b>c>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me a lot!

Comment: @HerrK. : I'm glad that I was able to help ;)